# Entity deleted on the server will remain unchanged on the client. Default breeze WebApi config

Tags: breeze

I'm having issue with entity removed on the server, which was not modified on the client.

As of v 1.3.3 it is now possible to modify the map of changed entities when overriding BeforeSaveEntities() on the server. If I mark an entity for deletion like this

`saveMap.Add(someEntity.GetType(), new List<EntityInfo>() { CreateEntityInfo(someEntity, EntityState.Deleted) });`

someEntity will be deleted from the db, but since on the client it was unchanged at the time saveChanges was called, it will remain unchanged after saveChanges finishes.

When you look at the payload returned by saveChanges from the server it is clear, that client has no clue that someEntity was deleted.

**Shouldn't server include the information that certain entity included in the returned payload was deleted?** This would allow the client to resolve the entity as deleted even if it was not marked as deleted when saveChanges was called.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good point, I'll try to look into it for one of the next releases.

This is an unusual case because normally the client is telling the server about a deletion so we don't need to send any information about the deletion back to the client.  In this case, though, you are deleting an entity on the server that was not deleted on the client.

But... I agree, we should support the ability to do this.